# Transferring multiple files from one folder to another using Terminal

Tags: terminal

I am a new user of macOS, so please accept my apology in advance if my question sounds very trivial or stupid.

I have a folder that contains 13000 images. I want to transfer those images into three different folders in such a way that five thousand images go into two different folders each and remaining 3 thousand go into the third folder.

After searching for a while, I used the following command to transfer first 5000 images but it didn't work. Here are my steps:

1. I went into the source folder that contains the images
2. Used this command to copy the images `cp  head -5000 ../Paras_valid`, but it did not work.

Could anyone help me how to copy the multiple files into different folders?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the name of the source folder and what are the names of the destination folders. What are their locations/path relative to the source folder?

Comment: Name of the source folder is Paras_all and both source and destination folder are located in the a folder called cell_images which is placed in Documents folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more difficult than it may seem. The following assumes that all images to be copied are in the same directory (no sub directories).

```bsh
cd "PATH/TO/Paras_all"
count=0
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.png' -print | while IFS= read line; do
    if [[ $count -lt 5000 ]]; then
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/TARGET1"
    elif [[ $count -lt 10000 ]]; then
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/TARGET2"
    else
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/TARGET3"
    fi
    ((count++))
done
```

Replace `-name '*.JPG'` to mach your images and `TARGET1` etc by the actual names. If you run the code like that it will just print the commands. Remove the `echo` if the commands seem to be correct.

PS: It's probably easiest to put everything in a file with `#!/bin/bash` in the first line, make the file executable with `chmod +x NAMEOFFILE` and then run `./NAMEOFFILE`.

Comment: Great solution by @nohillside — though since many JPEGs have the file extension in lowercase and/or include an E, I'd recommend changing `-name '*.JPG'` to `\( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg \)`.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for the solution. However, I dont under the changing of file -name parameter. The images I got have png extension and they have name like C33P1thinF_IMG_20150619_114756a_cell_179, C33P1thinF_IMG_20150619_114756a_cell_180, C33P1thinF_IMG_20150619_114756a_cell_181, something like that. Could you please guide me?

Comment: @user2293224 I've updated the answer to match all files ending in `.png`/`.PNG`. You can change the pattern to whatever you need, it works the same as in the shell itself.

Comment: Thanks, last thing before I run the script. In the first line where it is written "cd "PATH/TO/Paras_all" does it replace with "cd actual_path_of_Paras_all" or is it should be  as it is written in the answer??

Comment: @user2293224 You need to replace both the path in the first line and the ones ending in TARGET1/2/3 with the actual names.

Comment: @nohillside I ran the script and everything looked good when script finished, I checked the targated folder, files were not copied there. Here are few end lines of the script I copied for you: cp ./C91P52ThinF_IMG_20150821_123116_cell_190.png /Users/yasirmuhammad/Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Paraitized_test
cp ./C134P95ThinF_IMG_20151005_121048_cell_113.png /Users/yasirmuhammad/Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Paraitized_test
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: Snap shot of script : #!/bin/bash
cd "Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Parasitized_all"
count=0
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.png' -print | while IFS= read line; do
    if [[ $count -lt 5000 ]]; then
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Paraitized_train"
    elif [[ $count -lt 10000 ]]; then
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Paraitized_validation"
    else
        echo cp "$line" ~/"Documents/ludwig/cell_images/Paraitized_test"
    fi
    ((count++))
done

Comment: Please read my post carefully :-) As written the script doesn't copy anything, it just prints the copy statements to Temrinal. If these look ok for you, remove the `echo` in front of `cp` (on all three lines) and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

you can first go to Finder and open the folder with all the images. I would select all the files and right-click. One of the options you'll see when you right-click is to Rename 13000 files. If you click on this option you'll get a pane where you can rename the files in sequential order. You can define the first part of the name and it will add the sequential part.

Now create a folder for the first 5000 files. You can just select the first 5000 files and and create a shell script that runs from 1 to 5000 and run it from the new empty folder. The command that sets run 5000 times is, from the new directory, "cp ../old_folder_name/files_name_inum *".This will copy files *_00001 to *_05000 to you first new directory. Then make a 2nd directory and have you script run from *_05001 to *_10000 and finally run a third time to get the files 10001 to 13000.

The actual unix shell script is the following

```
for i in {0001..5000}
do
   cp ../old_imager_files/image_files_$i target1/
done
```